# JavaScript - How does Disqus handle its "disqus_config" function which contains undefined property?

Tags: javascript, function, undefined, disqus

Here is a part of the Disqus's "universal code":

```
var disqus_config = function () {
    this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
    this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
```

What I don't undestand is how Disqus handle this function, because `page` is `undefined`, so we cannot access to `identifier` or `url`.
I have tested several examples:

```
disqus_config();
console.log(disqus_config.page);
var a = new disqus_config();
```

But I still don't understand how Disqus handle this `undefined` element.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see, in the `embed.js` code it's something like this:

```
var _config = window.disqus_config;
window.disqus_config = function () {
    if (_config) _config.call(this);
    // Other stuff here....
};
```

So, before replacing it, disqus checks if it exists then runs it within its own scope.